# How to achieve a popup which contain data filters

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a popup in which I have a List of Filters, So when select on the filter the data should populate based on filter.[This is the Image I need to develop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JORUI.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/) from nuget .

> in iOS

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
      Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
      
      global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
      LoadApplication (new App ());
      return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
    }
}
```

> in Android

```
namespace HelloXamarinFormsWorld.Android
{
    [Activity(Label = "HelloXamarinFormsWorld", MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);
        
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication (new App ());
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

Create a subclass of

> in xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="xxx.MyPopupPage">
    <!--You can set an animation in the xaml file or in the csharp code behind-->
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <!--You can use any elements here which are extended from Xamarin.Forms.View-->
    <StackLayout >
      
      <Listview>
       
         // You can load the data here

      </Listview>

    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

> in code behind

```
public partial class MyPopupPage : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
    {
        public MyPopupPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
        }

        // ### Methods for supporting animations in your popup page ###

        // Invoked before an animation appearing
        protected override void OnAppearingAnimationBegin()
        {
            base.OnAppearingAnimationBegin();
        }

        // Invoked after an animation appearing
        protected override void OnAppearingAnimationEnd()
        {
            base.OnAppearingAnimationEnd();
        }

        // Invoked before an animation disappearing
        protected override void OnDisappearingAnimationBegin()
        {
            base.OnDisappearingAnimationBegin();
        }

        // Invoked after an animation disappearing
        protected override void OnDisappearingAnimationEnd()
        {
            base.OnDisappearingAnimationEnd();
        }

        protected override Task OnAppearingAnimationBeginAsync()
        {
            return base.OnAppearingAnimationBeginAsync();
        }

        protected override Task OnAppearingAnimationEndAsync()
        {
            return base.OnAppearingAnimationEndAsync();
        }

        protected override Task OnDisappearingAnimationBeginAsync()
        {
            return base.OnDisappearingAnimationBeginAsync();
        }

        protected override Task OnDisappearingAnimationEndAsync()
        {
            return base.OnDisappearingAnimationEndAsync();
        }

        // ### Overrided methods which can prevent closing a popup page ###

        // Invoked when a hardware back button is pressed
        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            // Return true if you don't want to close this popup page when a back button is pressed
            return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
        }

        // Invoked when background is clicked
        protected override bool OnBackgroundClicked()
        {
            // Return false if you don't want to close this popup page when a background of the popup page is clicked
            return base.OnBackgroundClicked();
        }
    }
```

For more details you can check https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as answer if it is helpful .